# Jenkins: S3 Copy Artifact Build parameters not supported in project name field

Tags: git, jenkins, amazon-s3, deployment, jenkins-plugins

In our jenkins Configuration, we have two Projects One Project(Multi Branch Free Style) is used to build .Net project and puts the artifacts on S3 bucket. The other project (Multi Branch Free Style) picks the artifacts from S3 bucket and deploys it to our webserver which is on seperate machine.

The settings that we have used in project 2:

1) Inject environment variables prior to Building.

```
#Multi branch 
MB_URL=MyFolder/MultiBranchProjName1/BranchName
```

2) Settings that we used for S3 bucket:

[image: S3 Copy artifacts settings in Multi branch Free Style project]

3) Console Log that gives us error when we click build now:

```
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
12:49:21 Unable to find project for artifact copy: MyFolder/MultiBranchProjName1/BranchName
12:49:21 This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.
```

Finally, when we go to individual branch specific child projects for project 2 and instead of using build parameter: ${MB_URL} we hard code path to project directly "MyFolder/MultiBranchProjName1/BranchName" then we see that the build process runs successfully.

**So, is there a way by which we can make "Copy S3 artifacts" to work with Build parameters or {BRANCH_NAME}**? or whether there is a work around for this.

**Note:**
Since we are new to Jenkins, we have tried following approaches also:

1. used variations of ${MB_URL}, $MB_URL
2. added ${MB_URL}, $MB_URL in the Build Configuration/Permission to Copy Artifact section of project 1 in addition to MyFolder/MultiBranchProjName2/* all seperated by (,)
3. Used MyFolder/MultiBranchProjName1/${BRANCH_NAME} in Project name section.
4. Both of our projects use Git plugin to create a Multi Branch project.

Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any work around/solution?

Comment: Same issue here while trying to publish artifacts to a ${BRANCH_NAME} directory on S3, it literally creates a folder called ${BRANCH_NAME} under the specified bucket... Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, still looking for it. As a work around I have hard coded name of branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I solved the problem by using Jenkins (Bitibucket/Github) Pipelines instead of Freestyle multibranch. Now the $BRANCH_NAME environment variable is properly defined.